# switch from Android platform to UWP platform

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, virtual-reality, hololens, oculus

I am using ASA and MRTK in Unity Project. At first, I build the app for HoloLens, then I switch to Android to build for an Oculus device. When I switch back to UWP, I faced this error:

Library\PackageCache\com.microsoft.azure.spatial-anchors-sdk.core@7b2d5f79f09a\Runtime\Scripts\SpatialAnchorManager.cs(517,90): error CS1061: 'CloudSpatialAnchor' does not contain a definition for 'OpenXrAnchor' and no accessible extension method 'OpenXrAnchor' accepting a first argument of type 'CloudSpatialAnchor' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Thank you in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced your issue, and I solved it by updating all the ASA packages used to the latest version. You can have a try.

[image]